# How to click on the reCAPTCHA using Selenium and Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, recaptcha, webdriverwait

Why am I getting errors when trying to get the driver to click on the reCAPTCHA button?

This is the site where I am trying to get it to work: https://rsps100.com/vote/760/

This is my current code so far:

```
WebElement iframeSwitch = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div/div/iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframeSwitch);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class=recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark]")).click();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To invoke `click()` on the **reCaptcha** *checkbox* as the element is within an `<iframe>` you need to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *elementToBeClickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    public class ReCaptcha_click {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.get("https://rsps100.com/vote/760");
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
            new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark"))).click();
        }
    }
    ```
- Browser Snapshot:

  [image: reCaptcha]

Comment: :You always steal our efforts :).I have run the code 10 times and it is working fine but OP complaing.

Comment: @KajalKundu I would love to see you succeed but yes following the best practices so the new contributors are guided in the best possible manner :) still your contributions are very helpful.

Comment: SO is really confusing when you provide entire code other contributor always complaining about that.When you give specific answer OP also confuse :)

Comment: for my case, I had to click on 'div.rc-anchor-content' element

Comment: Any tips on getting through the next part? Selecting correct images etc? @KunduK

Comment: As mentioned in the comments I also needed 'div.rc-anchor-content' but also the following: "//iframe[starts-with(@title, 'reCAPTCHA') and starts-with(@src, 'https://recaptcha.net')]"

Answer (score 3):

Use `WebDriverWait` to identify the element.See if this help.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name,'a-')]")));
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark")));
element.click();
```

Comment: is my xpath right? is my cssSelector thing right? i tried with your code and my code combination --> https://pastebin.com/g1pfzduq but it said "could not find element" and a lot of red errors in console

Comment: have you tried yourself? i got this error --- xpected condition failed: waiting for frame to be available: By.xpath: //iframe[starts-with(@name,'a-')] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval) ---    caused by: no such element

Comment: your frame is dynamic so i have written xpath like this.Copy the entire code with frame switching

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me. Please note that I am using Selenide. For regular selenium code look the same.

```
    import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;

    void recaptchaTest() {

        open("https://rsps100.com/vote/760");

        switchTo().frame($x("//iframe[starts-with(@name, 'a-') and starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]"));

        $("div.rc-anchor-content").click();

        switchTo().defaultContent();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that should work.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("a-9wt0e8vkopnm");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")).click();
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchFrameException: No frame element found by name or id a-9wt0e8vkopnm, is what i got when i tried your code. yes, i let the website load correctly until i executed these commands but still got the error

Comment: I think that's right name, but can you try with ID.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this maybe on the stupid way. But hawe in mind that I am not in test environment and I practicing automatization of tests. So this is my solution:

Beside using

```
public void notABot( ) {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds( 15 ));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[starts-with(@name,'a-') and starts-with (@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha')]")));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div [ @class =  'recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click( );
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
}
```

this, I also added custom send keys method

```
public void inputEmail( ) {

    inputEmail.click( );

    String email = Strings.EMAIL_FOR_SIGNUP;
    for (int i = 0; i < email.length(); i++) {

        char c = email.charAt(i);
        String s = new StringBuilder( ).append( c ).toString( );

        inputEmail.sendKeys( s );
        sleepSendKeys( );
    }
}
```

Sleep is 300 millis. In 96 procent time I manage to cheat google reCaptcha that actually human is login to the page. Its work for me