# CSS selector for reCAPTCHA checkbok using Selenium and VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, iframe, webdriverwait

On the website I am trying to fill in some fields on, there is a checkbox that I need to click to add the check mark in it:

```html
<div class="rc-anchor-content"><div class="rc-inline-block"><div class="rc-anchor-center-container"><div class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-holder"><span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox recaptcha-checkbox-expired" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation" style=""></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation" style=""></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation" style="transform: rotate(180deg);"></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinnerAnimation" role="presentation" style=""></div><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div></span></div></div></div><div class="rc-inline-block"><div class="rc-anchor-center-container"><label class="rc-anchor-center-item rc-anchor-checkbox-label" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="recaptcha-anchor-label"><span aria-live="polite" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-accessible-status"></span>I'm not a robot</label></div></div></div>
```

Using Selenium in VBA, I tried the following

```
.FindElementByCss("div.recaptcha-checkbox-border").Click
```

And also I tried

```
.FindElementByCss("span.recaptcha-checkbox").Click
```

But I got an error at this line.

Here's the link of the website to see the whole HTML
https://www.moj.gov.kw/AR/E-Gov/Pages/eServices01.aspx

Comment: If you could use selenium to bypass *I am not a robot* it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: This is the second post I've seen this week where someone is trying to do exactly what the site doesn't want them to do. It might be doable but what you are attempting to do may very well be illegal. I would strongly advice against it

Comment: @Zac Thanks a lot. I have edited the main post and removes any illegal requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the element, as the desired element is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce a waiter and switch to the desired frame.
- Induce a waiter for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  .SwitchToFrame.FindElementByXPath("//iframe[contains(@src, 'recaptcha') and not(@title='recaptcha challenge')]", timeout:=10000)
  .FindElementByCss("div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark").Click
  ```

You can find similar discussions in:

- [How to click on the reCaptcha using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264221/how-to-click-on-the-recaptcha-using-selenium-and-java/55265044#55265044)
- [Find the reCAPTCHA element and click on it — Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309#53917309)

> Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Thanks a lot for great help. I appreciate a lot your help.

Comment: @DebianjanB I have faced another similar page and I used Ctrl + F to find Xpath `div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark` and found three not only one. how can I specify the first one of them?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Let's discuss the issue in details in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.