# How can I bypass the Google CAPTCHA with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, recaptcha, captcha

How can I bypass the Google CAPTCHA using Selenium and Python?

When I try to scrape something, Google give me a CAPTCHA. Can I bypass the Google CAPTCHA with Selenium Python?

As an example, it's Google [reCAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReCAPTCHA). You can see this CAPTCHA via this link: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo

Comment: umm.. Then what's the point of a captcha?

Comment: I think the only way if you want to bypass a captcha is to use someone else's service. You pass them your captcha, they return you the text.

Comment: Sounds more do-able. I'm not going to try it. Probably find the coordinates of the checkbox element, send a click.

Comment: However, how are you getting captchas in the first place? Some of your actions must have triggered google to think you are a robot.

Comment: @HjSin I will improve that but can you please tell me how to bypass captcha

Comment: If it can be bypassed by bots then whats the point of having it in first place. If you are testing application having captcha, its better to test removing it temporarily.

Comment: Some of this gotcha is activated because you have repeatedly try multiple times using the same IP address. The other is because it may have detect you are using selenium. For the first one, you can change the ip address.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

To start with using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491)'s *Python* clients, you should avoid solving/bypass Google [CAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/captcha).

---

### Selenium

[Selenium](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/) automates browsers. Now, what you want to achieve with that power is entirely up to individuals, but primarily it is for automating web applications through browser clients for testing purposes and of coarse it is certainly not limited to that.

---

### CAPTCHA

On the other hand, [CAPTCHA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA) (the acronym being *...Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart...*) is a type of challenge–response test used in computing to determine if the user is human.

So, *Selenium* and *CAPTCHA* serves two completely different purposes and ideally shouldn't be used to achieve any interrelated tasks.

Having said that, [reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recaptcha) can easily detect the network traffic and identify your program as a *Selenium* driven **bot**.

---

### Generic Solution

However, there are some generic approaches to avoid getting detected while web scraping:

- The first and foremost attribute a website can determine your script/program by is through your **monitor size**. So it is recommended **not** to use the conventional [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp).
- If you need to send multiple requests to a website, keep on changing the **User Agent** on each request. Here you can find a detailed discussion on *[Way to change Google Chrome user agent in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49565042/way-to-change-google-chrome-user-agent-in-selenium/49565254#49565254)*
- To simulate *humanlike* behavior, you may require to slow down the script execution even beyond [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) and [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) inducing `time.sleep(secs)`. Here you can find a detailed discussion on *[How to sleep Selenium WebDriver in Python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)*

---

### This use case

However, in a couple of use cases we were able to interact with the [reCAPTCHA](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo) using *Selenium* and you can find more details in the following discussions:

- *[How to click on the reCAPTCHA using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264221/how-to-click-on-the-recaptcha-using-selenium-and-java/55265044#55265044)*
- *[CSS selector for reCAPTCHA checkbok using Selenium and VBA Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074490/css-selector-for-recaptcha-checkbok-using-selenium-and-vba-excel/57077202#57077202)*
- *[Find the reCAPTCHA element and click on it — Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309#53917309)*

---

### References

You can find a couple of related discussion in:

- *[How can I make a Selenium script undetectable using GeckoDriver and Firefox through Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58873022/how-to-make-selenium-script-undetectable-using-geckodriver-and-firefox-through-p/58879076#58879076)*
- *[Is there a version of Selenium WebDriver that is not detectable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528631/is-there-a-version-of-selenium-that-is-not-detectable-can-selenium-be-truly-un/56529616#56529616)*

---

### tl; dr

- *[How does reCAPTCHA 3 know I'm using Selenium/chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835)*

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on "the conventional Viewport"? What does it refer to?

Comment: Changing my viewport to 100, 100 worked for me.

Comment: I think HTTP cookies are important too. How you read it, keep it and when to clear them can help in some situations to avoid captchas

Comment: waw... this is a nice step i will try to implement it right away! Thanks @undetectedSelenium you're my saviour!

Answer (score 20):

In order to bypass the CAPTCHA when scraping Google, you have to manually solve a CAPTCHA and export the cookies Google gives you. Now, every time you open a Selenium WebDriver, make sure you add the cookies you exported. The GOOGLE_ABUSE_EXEMPTION cookie is the one you're looking for, but I would save all cookies just to be on the safe side.

If you want an additional layer of stability in your scrapes, you should export several cookies and have your script randomly select one of them each time you ping Google.

These cookies have a long expiration date so you wouldn't need to get new cookies every day.

For help on saving and loading cookies in Python and Selenium, you should check out this answer: *[How to save and load cookies using Python + Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver/15058521#15058521)*

Comment: Hello, I'm new to using cookies; after finding the GOOGLE_ABUSE_EXEMPTION cookie, how do you use that specific cookie? Read the link you provided, but that seems like it saves the cookie from the previous session, rather than a specific cookie value that we already have

Comment: Hi, Yu Na! The link shows how to save all cookies and then load them. I tried it in my code and it works like a charm. If there's a specific roadblock you're having, open up a new SO question with your code example and PM me the link so I can see if I can help :)

Answer (score 3):

Clear Browsing History, cached data, cookies and other site data
First Create an Google Account while you are in browser window opened by selenium.
Sign in to your account

```
wd.get("https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?hl=en&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F%3Fgws_rd%3Dssl&ec=GAZAmgQ&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin");
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    wd.findElement(By.name("identifier")).sendKeys("Email"+Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    wd.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("Password"+Keys.ENTER);
    Thread.sleep(5000);
```

Then Open any website that uses recaptcha tick on checkmark using this code

```
String framename=wd.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")).getAttribute("name");
            wd.switchTo().frame(framename);
    wd.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']")).click();
```

You won't find any Puzzles or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Bypass as in solve it or bypass  as in never get it at all?

To solve it:

- sign up with 2captcha, capmonster cloud, deathbycaptcha, etc. and follow their instructions. They will give you a token that you pass with the form.

To never get it at all:

- Make sure you have good IP reputation (most important for Cloudflare).
- Make sure you have a good browser fingerprint (most important for Distil) - I recommend puppeteer + the stealth plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Ok,  so there is a simple python script to solve captcha for you.

It basically read the audio and then use google assistant to convert it into text and paste it.

It is only workable in audio captchas which is given the most case with imahe captcha V2

https://github.com/ohyicong/recaptcha_v2_solver

Disclaimer!

I do not write the script, i just get an idea of doing this but got this brother project so, thought to help others through this.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In case, you have access to config, add
SiteKey: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAJcZVRqyHh71UMIEGNQ_MXjiZKhI
SecretKey: 6LeIxAcTAAAAAGG-vFI1TnRWxMZNFuojJ4WifJWe

See: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#id-like-to-run-automated-tests-with-recaptcha.-what-should-i-do

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34926642)