# Open Source Methods to Block Selenium-based bots from websites

Tags: selenium, security, selenium-webdriver, bots, websecurity

I'm starting a site that may get a lot of attention from trolling bots in the comments or email.

One of the most common bot frameworks appears to be [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/).

How do I detect and block Selenium-based bots? I would prefer open-source frameworks so that I can update code in real-time.  The site is basically using JavaScript, HTML5 and CSS hosted on Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Requiring Google recaptcha before submitting a comment or email will be very affective.

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3.html

Answer (score 1):

You saw it right. These days one of the most common and popular [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) frameworks are based on [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871).

However, Selenium driven WebDriver controlled *Browsing Contexts* are easy to detect and corrective measures can be implemented in different ways as follows:

- Implementing [captcha](/questions/tagged/captcha) / [recaptcha](/questions/tagged/recaptcha) to detect the *automatic bots*.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How does recaptcha 3 know I'm using selenium/chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835)

- Detecting the term **HeadlessChrome** within *headless Chrome UserAgent*

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Access Denied page with headless Chrome on Linux while headed Chrome works on windows using Selenium through Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59323836/access-denied-page-with-headless-chrome-on-linux-while-headed-chrome-works-on-wi/59331061#59331061)

- Using **Bot Management service** from [**Distil Networks**](https://www.distilnetworks.com/)

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Unable to use Selenium to automate Chase site login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605757/unable-to-use-selenium-to-automate-chase-site-login/54284776#54284776)

- Using **Bot Manager service** from [**Akamai**](https://www.akamai.com/us/en/products/security/bot-manager.jsp)

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Dynamic dropdown doesn't populate with auto suggestions on https://www.nseindia.com/ when values are passed using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457093/dynamic-dropdown-doesnt-populate-with-auto-suggestions-on-https-www-nseindia/62457673#62457673)

- Using **Bot Protection service** from [**Datadome**](https://datadome.co/product/)

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Website using DataDome gets captcha blocked while scraping using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199222/website-using-datadome-gets-captcha-blocked-while-scraping-using-selenium-and-py/62205253#62205253)

---

### References

You can find a relevant discussions in:

- [Can a website detect when you are using selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver/62520191#62520191)