# Can Selenium automation be tracked?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, bots, botdetect

Is it possible to track if you are using automation tool to do things automatically?

Can someone please answer my question?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) / [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) initiated [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) / [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) *Browsing Context* can be easily [detected](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447) deploying either of the following Bot Management services:

- [*Imperva Advanced Bot Protection*](https://www.imperva.com/products/advanced-bot-protection-management/) formerly known as [Distil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54284776/7429447).
- [*Akamai Bot Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62457673/7429447)
- [*DataDome*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62205253/7429447)
- [*Cloudflare*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64960149/7429447)

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Can a website detect when you are using Selenium with chromedriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62520191/7429447)