# 403 forbidden python windows vs linux

Tags: python, web-scraping, server, http-error

When running Python requests from a window's desktop (Python 3.11.4), it works fine; once running from Linux's server (Python 3.8.6 or Python 3.10.1), it returns 403 code forbidden (please enable JS or disable any ad blocker).

```
import requests

payload = {
    'VoyageReference': '',
    'VesselReference': 'CMA CGM A. LINCOLN ; CGLCO'
}  

headers = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

r = requests.get('https://www.cma-cgm.com/ebusiness/schedules/voyage/detail', params=payload, headers=headers)
```

Same behavior with sessions and different modules such as urllib, requests_html, etc.
I have tried proxies as well do be sure that ip is not banned.
Website is not protected by Cloudfare, no authorization needed.
Many combinattions of headers were tested including cookies(which are acttually not required).
selenium is not solution for this question.

fake request from postman
[( no captcha offered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wodfA.png)

UPD:
[response headers from Win and linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdsyH.png)

Comment: Are the Windows and Linux machines on the same network, or different networks?

Comment: @JohnGordon they are on different network. windows is home PC and linux is machine of hosting provider

Comment: _Website is not protected by Cloudfare_ How do you know this?

Comment: Perhaps the website doesn't like the Linux machine's IP domain.

Comment: It's probably not due to requesting via Linux vs Windows. You could test this by running your code in a Linux docker container on your Windows machine. FWIW I get a 200 response from your Python code on macOS at home. I would guess maybe they try to block IPs which scrape them, maybe including your hosting provider?  Another test would be to request other websites from the Linux server (does the 403 definitely come from the target website?)

Comment: @JohnGordon https://checkforcloudflare.selesti.com/

Comment: @Anentropic actually initial code does two requests. first request to get data for parameters and second request to get data based on parameters. both requests are independent and second request which is mentioned in topic can run without cookies etc from first request. moreover i thried session with two requests togeter and same story. on one link it works fine on both machines and second link works on windows only.

Comment: i just interesting is there any difference on linux machin in sending requests?any extra headers may be added from apache server?

Comment: why/how would apache server be involved?

Comment: The difference is very likely due to the IP domains of the two machines, not any actual difference in the requests.

Comment: @Anentropic there is Apache HTTP Server on the same machine with working web site.

Comment: @JohnGordon i have used proxies but same issue exists

Comment: <html><head><title>cma-cgm.com</title><style>#cmsg{animation: A 1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}</style></head><body style="margin:0"><p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p><script data-cfasync="false">var dd={'rt':'c','cid':'AHrlqAAAAAMAqB7ko9-4h1kAXyXxnQ==','hsh':'490A8A2485BA28921F861A802754DD','t':'bv','s':39232,'e':'df97a48900986d7b832cdb49282eeb4430f08cc5d47259a7b957f3b122cd8243','host':'geo.captcha-delivery.com'}</script><script data-cfasync="false" src="https://ct.captcha-delivery.com/c.js"></script></body></html>

Comment: it's serving you a captcha - they likely think there's something suspicious about the origin of your request

Comment: @Anentropic there is no offering captcha. if i get fake request(without headers) its just say enable JS...

Comment: Postman is not showing you the captcha because it is not executing the JS to display the captcha - you get the fallback text instead. We can see this in the content you pasted in previous comment... there is a script tag for a captcha at the end

Comment: local work almost always uses laxer security that production, so: did you remember to turn on auth enforcement locally or run in production mode locally to make sure it actually runs the same? Because that 403 means "things are working perfectly fine, there are no errors with your request or with me servicing that request, but I'm not letting you access this resource because you haven't authenticated properly. Show me the cookie, auth header, user:pass information, query arguments, or POST payload that proves I can trust you"

Comment: Datadome sees a bunch of Linux clients connecting through 1280x720 windows, then it can simply deduce that this sort of setup is likely a bot and gives everyone with these fingerprint details low trust scores [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62199222/website-using-datadome-gets-captcha-blocked-while-scraping-using-selenium-and-py