# How to get rid of captha in selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I want to login in google account using selenuim, captha is showing up. I use user-agent but it doesn't help. Can someone help me, please?

[Captha picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1fiP.jpg)

```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.85 Safari/537.36")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver", options=options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
```

Comment: How to get rid of captha in selenium? - ask the ops to provide you captcha free environment.

Comment: what do you mean by ask the "ops" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.
You literally CAN NOT bypass captcha with selenium.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58872451/how-can-i-bypass-the-google-captcha-with-selenium-and-python) more about it

Comment: Should not that have been a comment ?

Comment: I think no since this is an answer to this question. I'm not sure each and every answer have to be long and contain code.

Comment: Well if someone simply Google this - how to automate captcha they will get to know whatever you have written above.

Comment: Correct. Moreover, with some googling you can resolve most questions asked here. And not only here.

Comment: depends on which captcha, 1,2, or 3 (in 3 there is no solutions)