# How to locate and click on the recaptcha checkbox using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, iframe, css-selectors

I've already tried in several ways to click this checkbox with selenium and I couldn't.
Link: http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/email.do?metodo=apresentar&seqIdPessoa=246740&nomeDestinatario=Maria_Jos%E9_Panichi_Vieira
I already tried with XPATH, with CLASS_NAME and others, but the return is always the same:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element:
```

Can anyone help me?

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from capmonster_python import RecaptchaV2Task

class ChromeAuto:
    def __init__(self):
        options = Options()
        ua = UserAgent()
        self.userAgent = ua.random
        print(self.userAgent)
        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={self.userAgent}')
        self.driver_path = r'chromedriver'
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_argument('--profile-directory=1')
        self.options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
        self.options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
        self.captcha = RecaptchaV2Task("c6eea325a7a78273c062d2bb23a2a43d")

        self.chrome = webdriver.Chrome(
            self.driver_path,
            options=self.options
        )
    def test(self):
        self.chrome.get('http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/email.do?metodo=apresentar&seqIdPessoa=246740&nomeDestinatario=Maria_Jos%E9_Panichi_Vieira')
        sleep(5)
        self.chrome.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="recaptcha-anchor"]/div[1]').click()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome = ChromeAuto()
    chrome.test()
```

Comment: does this help https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-handle-captcha-in-selenium#:~:text=While%20automating%20Captcha%20is%20not,manually%20solve%20Captcha%20while%20testing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*ReCaptcha*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55502835/7429447) checkbox is within an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447) so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    driver.get('http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/email.do?metodo=apresentar&seqIdPessoa=246740&nomeDestinatario=Maria_Jos%E9_Panichi_Vieira')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='reCAPTCHA']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-border"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    driver.get('http://buscatextual.cnpq.br/buscatextual/email.do?metodo=apresentar&seqIdPessoa=246740&nomeDestinatario=Maria_Jos%E9_Panichi_Vieira')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-border"))).click()
    ```

> PS: Clicking on the [**ReCaptcha**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58876531/7429447) checkbox opens the image selection panel.

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: click_captcha]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)