# How to interact with the reCAPTCHA audio element using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, recaptcha, webdriverwait

I want to, click on the button to resolve the captcha through the audio, but selenium does not detect the specified "id".

```
browser.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
mainWin = browser.current_window_handle  
iframe = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("iframe")[0]
browser.switch_to_frame(iframe)
CheckBox = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID ,"recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
sleep(4)
audio = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID ,"recaptcha-audio-button"))).click()
```

Comment: captcha is made to stop bot activity, and selenium is kind of in that category you cant do much

Comment: And there is no way to prevent me from detecting my bot?

Answer (score 5):

To `click()` on the button to resolve the captcha through the audio as the desired elements are within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):
- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
  driver.switch_to.default_content()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#recaptcha-audio-button"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: audio_captcha]

---

### Reference

[Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447)

---

### Outro

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to click on the reCaptcha using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264221/how-to-click-on-the-recaptcha-using-selenium-and-java/55265044#55265044)
- [CSS selector for reCaptcha checkbok using Selenium and vba excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57074490/css-selector-for-recaptcha-checkbok-using-selenium-and-vba-excel/57077202#57077202)
- [Find the reCAPTCHA element and click on it — Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309#53917309)

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering.
It really didn't work, it records the following error: raise TimeoutException (message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @Msthiue12 At which line are you seeing _TimeoutException_? Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Answer (score 1):

Very useful, just put your attention, that text: **'recaptcha challenge'** in selector below depends from regional settings/language:

```
     WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']")))
```