# ReCaptcha download audio file?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

Please let me know of what I'm doing wrong

Using the code from: [How to interact with the reCAPTCHA audio element using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077053/how-to-interact-with-the-recaptcha-audio-element-using-selenium-and-python)

I want next to get the src file for the audio to download it, so I wrote exactly after the end of the provided code the following:

```
# get the mp3 audio file
src = driver.find_element_by_id("audio-source").get_attribute("src")
```

But Python returns run time error saying:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="audio-source"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.96)
```

**Note: I copied that code as is, and only added the last line**

For your convince here is my full code:

```
def tmp():
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

    # recaptcha libraries
    import speech_recognition as sr
    import urllib
    # import pydub

    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='/Users/ahmad/Desktop/chromedriver')
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#recaptcha-audio-button"))).click()

    # get the mp3 audio file
    src = driver.find_element_by_id("audio-source").get_attribute("src")
```

[image]

---

I tried on nearby element the following to get it's href value and it worked, my only problem is with what is above:

```
src=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.rc-audiochallenge-tdownload-link"))).text

src=src.get_attribute('href')

print(src)
```

the element it worked on was:

[image]

---

I tried this too:

```
src=WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.invisibility_of_element((By.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"audio-source\"]")))

src=src.get_attribute('src')
```

But I get an error:

```
src=src.get_attribute('src')
```

AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'

Comment: The code as shown cannot be the full code. It at least has wrong indentation and misses imports.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi fixed it but that didn't have any impact especially that it's the same code posted an answer there

Comment: The point is not to fix it for you. The point is to provide a [mcve] for us.

Comment: an example is already provided, the google page is publicly available too and I have added an image of its html code, I'm already inside that frame but don't know what's the problem

Comment: I am not sure how you passed this line `iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor` because there is no such iframe at `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo`

Comment: It's in the code of the other question and runs find, the line I added causes the issue

Comment: @AlexeyR. I have added an image to that frame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(
    (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#recaptcha-anchor"))).click()
driver.switch_to.default_content()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='recaptcha challenge']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#recaptcha-audio-button"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".rc-audiochallenge-play-button button")))

# get the mp3 audio file

src = driver.find_element_by_id("audio-source").get_attribute("src")
print(src)
```

Just add one more wiat for the .rc-audiochallenge-play-button button

to download you should use:

```
import urllib.request
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "src.mp3")
```

Comment: why in wait you have click?

Comment: i removed it you don't need it even if its there its ok

Comment: Plus, please note 'audio-source' is different and not contained in audiochallenge-play-button

Comment: i am not retrieving that you should wait for that audio play prompt to appear before you could retrieve src attribute , src attribute is still retreived from the same audo-source