# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".recaptcha-checkbox-border"}

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, iframe, recaptcha, webdriverwait

I am trying to bypass the captcha verification using Selenium but I keep getting this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".recaptcha-checkbox-border"}
```

I have already tried using `sleep(20)` and it doesn't work. Here is the link that I am trying to bypass captcha on: https://whitepages.co.nz/ycaptcha?next=%2Fwhite-all%2Fhalswell%2Fchristchurch%2F

Please let me know if I am making a mistake in the the selector class or anything.

Comment: Your object is in an 'iframe' - you need to switch to that frame in order to identify it with selenium... However - If this site has a captcha it doesn't want you automating it, this will be the tip of the iceberg in issues you'll face. Captchas are designed to stop bots 
& automation - if they didn't work, people wouldn't use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reCAPTCHA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55501524/how-does-recaptcha-3-know-im-using-selenium-chromedriver/55502835#55502835) is within an `<iframe>` so you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://whitepages.co.nz/ycaptcha?next=%2Fwhite-all%2Fhalswell%2Fchristchurch%2F")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor']")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.recaptcha-checkbox-border"))).click()
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://whitepages.co.nz/ycaptcha?next=%2Fwhite-all%2Fhalswell%2Fchristchurch%2F")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='recaptcha-checkbox-border']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: whitepages]

---

### Reference

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
- [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)
- [Selenium “selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException” when using Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294)
- [How to interact with the reCAPTCHA audio element using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59077053/how-to-interact-with-the-recaptcha-audio-element-using-selenium-and-python/59078719#59078719)
- [Find the reCAPTCHA element and click on it — Python + Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53917157/find-the-recaptcha-element-and-click-on-it-python-selenium/53917309#53917309)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the code works now without any hassles.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LepxvIZAAAAAPGd49tlErQ-2da9Bh-3yN_gCjul&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93aGl0ZXBhZ2VzLmNvLm56OjQ0Mw..&amp;hl=en&amp;v=2Mfykwl2mlvyQZQ3PEgoH710&amp;size=normal&amp;cb=r4uh76mv0o72" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-taqeeo56s3nk" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
```

Switch over to the iframe after you get the sitekey.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://whitepages.co.nz/ycaptcha?next=%2Fwhite-all%2Fhalswell%2Fchristchurch%2F")
print(driver.find_element_by_class_name("g-recaptcha").get_attribute("data-sitekey"))
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#contentMainSearchResults > form > div > div > div > iframe")))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Does switch over to the iframe have any dependency on the _data-sitekey_?

Comment: Not really it's just after he needs his key for captcha verification. It's where he'll put it under.