# How to identify the reCAPTCHA element within in the WebUI and/or work with reCAPTCHA in automation?

Tags: javascript, groovy, katalon-studio

First of all, I'm an absolute noob and have only just started learning code - this is my first proper project and I think I'm at the final hurdle.

I'm currently trying to create a bot (with Katalon Studio, which is similar to Selenium) but are having a problem with the reCAPTCHA element. Yes, I understand the premise of reCAPTCHA and it's designed for this exact reason but it's becoming a pain in the ass when trying to test and build out the bot whenever I have to log in and complete the reCAPTURE exercise every single time. It's also an essential part of moving from page-to-page.

I have discovered a Chrome Extension which essentially transcribes the audio capture into text and solves it. However, I'm having actually having trouble locating and identifying the reCAPTCHA object element within the WebUI - I think it's due to being contained within an iframe and it's done like this on purpose.

There appear to be solutions using Selenium as I've found the following two links which suggest it is possible:

[How to click on the reCAPTCHA using Selenium and Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264221/how-to-click-on-the-recaptcha-using-selenium-and-java)

https://www.browserstack.com/guide/how-to-handle-captcha-in-selenium

I'm wondering if anyone has experience around this or any suggestions / advice / better ways of approaching this? I'm open to try anything as this is the last hurdle in getting the bot fully up and running - I don't really want to give up as it's my first project and will majorly help out a friend.

Speaking to the domain owner isn't an option and allowing them to disable reCAPTCHA is not an option. Are there workarounds / other Chrome extensions that I should look into?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a custom version of your app explicitly to be run by bot where captcha would be disabled?

Answer (score 2):

Well reCaptcha is made to protect websites from bots, you shouldn't even try to break it in the first place, maybe try using the API, if it exists, instead.

If the API don't exists maybe use OAuth2/ask the user to complete it, don't try to break it with a bot, it is very hard, and most of all shouldn't be done.